# PyODBC syntax error with attempted CSV file insertion

Tags: sql, sql-server, pyodbc

```
for fileName in fileNames:
   with open(fileName, mode="rt", encoding="utf-8", newline="") as csvfile:
        csvFile = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        header = next(csvFile)
        headers = map((lambda x: x.strip()), header)
        insert = 'INSERT INTO TEST ('.format(tableChoice) + ', '.join(headers) + ') VALUES '
        for row , record in enumerate(csvFile, start=1):
            values = map((lambda x: "'"+x.strip()+"'"), record)

            myCursor.execute(insert +'('+ ', '.join(values) +');' )
            cnxn.commit()
```

I get the below error when I reach the `execute` line in the script.  I just need the data extracted from the csv to be inserted into the database, row by row.  Anyone know what's causing the error?

> ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '-'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Edit:

The SQL query string is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO TEST (this, that, those) VALUES ('1', '11', '111');
INSERT INTO TEST (this, that, those) VALUES ('2', '22', '222');
INSERT INTO TEST (this, that, those) VALUES ('3', '33', '333');
```

Comment: Show us the final SQL, as it is passed to the server.

Comment: Edited original post

Comment: What does the query look like with the actual file that causes the error? I'd be expecting to see that one of the CSV headers contains a hyphen (-), or one of the CSV data values contain the sequence `'-`.

Comment: The source file has several hundred columns.  Can't really post something that large here.  Should I just remove the hyphens?

Comment: Sounds like you should be delimit identifiying the column names, if they have hyphens (`-`) in them. Or, better yet, change the names of your objects so that they don't need to be delimit identified in the first place.

Comment: When you build your list of column names you should use `", ".join([f"[{x}]" for x in headers])`

Comment: In addition, you really should parameterize your query and if your CSV files have any more than a few dozen rows you should also use `myCursor.fast_executemany = True`

Answer (score 1):

Likely issue is due to special characters in your column names such as `-` which requires wrapping in square brackets to escape in SQL Server. Additionally, consider using consistent Python string formatting and `csv.DictReader` to build a parameterized query followed by `executemany` for insertion:

```
for fileName in fileNames:
   with open(fileName, mode="rt", encoding="utf-8", newline="") as csvfile:
       reader = csv.DictReader(f)
       data = [row for row in reader]

       # BUILD SQL WITH [...] ESCAPED COLUMNS AND ? PARAM PLACEHOLDERS
       sql = "INSERT INTO [Test] ([{cols}]) VALUES ({prms})"
       sql = sql.format(cols="], [".join(map(lambda x: x.strip(), data[0].keys())), 
                        prms=", ".join(['?'] * len(data[0])))    
 
       # APPEND ALL ROWS AND BIND PARAMS
       myCursor.executemany(sql, [list(d.values()) for d in data])
       cnxn.commit()
```